# Modifying the position of title text content placeholder in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, breadcrumbs

I am a beginner in SharePoint and I have a SP 2010 teamsite where in my aim (for now) is to modify the web header and title.

Under the style tag "s4-titletext" which contains the title of the page followed by navigation link (I assume that is breadcrumb navigation), I would like to shift the whole block below the title icon instead of beside it...

Is there an OOTB to do this? or would I have to go through the designer?

I tried the Designer way and was able to shift the block below the title icon, however it shows me only the Site title and not the breadcrumb link.....

```
<td class="s4-titletext" >
                                    <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
                                            <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
                                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                    </h1>
                                    <span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep">
                                    <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/> </span>
                                    <h2>
                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="s4-pagedescription" tabindex="0" >
                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
```

Where am I possibly going wrong.... :(